# Weird route behaivor for show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, pluralize

I am making an application with all the model names in spanish. I am having some strange issues related with the singularization.
My model:

```
class Artista < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :fecha, :foto, :instrumento, :nombre
end
```

My model name is "artista" (artist) in singular.

Controller:

```
class ArtistasController < ApplicationController
  # GET /bandas
  # GET /bandas.json
  def index
    @artistas = Artista.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @artistas }
    end 
  end 

  def show
    @artista = Artista.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @artista }
    end 
  end 
  def new
    @artista = Artista.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @artista }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @artista = Artista.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @artista = Artista.new(params[:artista])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @artista.save
format.html { redirect_to @artista, notice: 'Artista was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @artista, status: :created, location: @artista }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @artista.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @artista = Artista.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @artista.update_attributes(params[:banda])
        format.html { redirect_to @artista, notice: 'Artista was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
 else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @artista.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end
  def destroy
    @artista = Artista.find(params[:id])
    @artista.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to artistas_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end
   end
```

(All this has been automatically created with the rails generate commands)

Now, my routes include the following:

```
resources :artistas
```

When I access `localhost:3000/artistas` everything works great. I can see the list of already created aritsts. Now, when I click on an existing artist (or after I try to create a new one, being redirected to the show artist page) for some strange reason it goes to `http://localhost:3000/artistum.3` (3 being the id of the artist I clicked on). The output for that url is a completely blank page.

I have never even typed the word artistum. I don't know where it got it from. Besides, it has a dot instead of a slash to separate the name from the id, so i dont know how to redirect it.

I ran a grep search of the folder containing everything and the word artistum exists only in log files.

My guess is that somehow part of my application thinks "artista" is plural and "artistum" is its singular form.

I added to my routes `match '/artistum' => 'artistas#index'`and that works for the index page, but the dot has me confused on how to do it for the show pages.

Can someone help me A) find out why its trying to get there or b) how to route from those show pages?
Thanks!

Comment: How does the `link_to` for clicking each individual `Artista` look like?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

Add this to the `inflections.rb` in the `config/initializers` folder:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'artista', 'artistas'
  inflect.irregular 'artista', 'artistas'
end
```